# stable diffusion via collab ignores reference photo from controlnet

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I installed Stable Diffusion via collab (Copy of StableDiffusion_EliAI.ipynb). But when I upload a photo to "img2img" and "controlnet" as a reference, stable diffusion simply ignores the reference when generating it and generates something separate according to the description in the prompt.

I used Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge browsers

How to solve this problem?

the uploaded picture as a reference should have been animated. exactly the same picture should have turned into a drawn one, but in the end stable diffusion simply ignores the reference uploaded to controlnet and generates pictures according to the description in the prompt or simply arbitrary ones if there is no description in the prompt.